# How to combine settings from multiple locales in Linux?

Tags: linux, date, locale, unicode, metric

When I installed Linux I set my locale to `en_US.UTF-8`. However I want to override some but not all of the settings in that locale. Specifically, I would like the `Measurement` to be `Metric` instead of `Imperial` and  the `Date` to be `DD/MM/YYYY` instead of `MM/DD/YYYY`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, and any of the `LC_*` environment variables individually.

e.g. my system defaults to `LANG=en_AU.UTF8`, but I want YYYY-MM-DD dates (in English) so I have `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF8`.

You can see a list of the variables and their current values by running `locale`:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF8
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF8"
LC_ALL=
```

See `man locale` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If only running some Desktop Environment and related applications then chances are high that the DE offers some system-settings graphical facility enabling to tune the language settings you want (measurement and date) (*1).

If sometimes login in from some tty console (not X-terminal) you will need to explicitly export some variables in your shell profile file as in my .bash_profile :

```
export LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Of course, if you launch your DE from the shell, its own settings will override these shell preferences.

Also be aware that many applications including some X terminal emulators, mail clients, *libreoffice*… comply with their own settings the user can manage via some dedicated preferences graphical utility. These settings will (locally) override settings made elsewhere.

---

**1 :** There are [other locale preferences](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1.html) users can wish setting individually that cannot be changed via some DE system-settings and that will be more or less correctly inferred from other settings.

Those LC_* variables can be exported and honored as session environment variables at the condition they are exported in the DE specific environment setting file or directory.
In particular regarding kde-Plasma : `$HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/env`
Refer to your specific DE's manual in order to discover where its session environment variables should be set.